# How to copy data from spreadsheet into a pdf?

Tags: python, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I have a pdf that has 6 text fields each for a number and description. They are Text6.0,Text6.1 etc. for the number field, and Text8.0,Text8.1 etc. for the description that I want. There is only room on this pdf template for those 6 things, but i have a list of sometimes 200+ that i want to automatically populate a document with the data and create pages as needed. The data is in a excel sheet with the first row and column titled Number, and the second column Description.

```
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
import pandas as pd

# Open the PDF template using PyMuPDF
pdf_template = fitz.open('Template rev 2.pdf') #omit personal data

# Read data from an Excel spreadsheet
excel_data = pd.read_excel('Date TEST.xlsx') #omit personal data

# Define the maximum number of entries per page
entries_per_page = 6

pdf_writer = fitz.open()
pdf_page = None
field_index = 0  # Initialize field index

for row_index, row in excel_data.iterrows():
    if row_index % entries_per_page == 0:
        if pdf_page is not None:
            pdf_writer.insert_pdf(pdf_page)
        pdf_page = pdf_template.load_page(0)  # Load a new page from the template
        field_index = 0  # Reset field index for the new page

    for i in range(entries_per_page):
        pdf_field_description = f'Text6.{field_index}'
        pdf_field_number = f'Text8.{field_index}'

        # Get the text fields by their field names
        description_coords = pdf_page.search_for(pdf_field_description)
        number_coords = pdf_page.search_for(pdf_field_number)

        # Create a new page with updated text
        page = pdf_template.load_page(0)
        page.insert_text(description_coords[0], row['Description'])
        page.insert_text(number_coords[0], row['Number'])

        # Replace the existing page with the updated one
        pdf_template.updatePage(page)

        field_index += 1

# Add the last page
if pdf_page is not None:
    pdf_writer.insert_pdf(pdf_page)

# Save the filled-out PDF
pdf_writer.save('output.pdf')
```

keeps throwing various errors, im very new to python and only trying it because adobe will not do what i need.

```
line 34, in <module>
    page.insert_text(discrepancy_coords[0], row['Discrepancy'])
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Again, I am very new to coding/python and would like the simplest solution to autofill my pdfs.

Comment: Can you add / paste in what sorts of various errors you're recieving?

Comment: I have added one of the many i have received.

Comment: what is the content of 'Template rev 2.pdf' and 'Date TEST.xlsx' look like ?